# SameSite=None is becoming another cookie

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, samesite

I am setting cookie through headers in Scala (2.10)/Play Framework (2.3). I am thinking of doing it this way o/w I will have to update the framework to use in-built functionality which I cannot do as of now. Below is my code for reference:

```
Test URL: https://elbtest.s2d6.com/x/?x=c&z=s&v=7100096
```

```
val cookieString = "949413017=533c892b32cf4a46961a38f8c56b33eb320412596|6386|323064|7100096|14988;SameSite=None;Expires=Wed, 30 Sep 2020 12:45:30 GMT;Path=/;Domain=s2d6.com;Secure"
val finalURL = "https://www.google.com/"
resp = Redirect(finalURL).withHeaders(SET_COOKIE -> cookieString)
```

In the browser, the above cookie '**949413017**' is being set but along with another cookie with name 'SameSite'. Because of this, I am unable to access my cookie in the requests that follows. PFA the response in browser:
[image]

**Chrome Version:** Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Any help in understanding in why this is happening is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: To the right of the "Response Headers" section, there should be a button "view source"; this will show the raw bytes received from the server. Could you screenshot or copy-paste that? If the Chrome cookie parser is Doing The Wrong Thing on the raw data, the parsed version won't tell you much.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `withHeaders` using `SET_COOKIE`.  You should be using the built-in cookie:

```
Redirect(finalURL).withCookies(Cookie("theme", "blue"))
```

See https://blog.knoldus.com/using-cookies-in-play-framework/ for an example.

Comment: Will, i am using play version 2.3 as I have mentioned in the first line of my question. Play 2.3 doesn't support samesite flag. I can't upgrade it. Hence, I am using headers to set cookie and append this flag.

Answer (score 0):

Just A tip ,if we use `SameSite=None` anywhere in the value of the `Set-Cookie header`, then Play Framework mistakenly see that as the beginning of another cookie !

What about using the standard header `Set-Cookie`?

`Set-Cookie: flavor=choco; SameSite=None; Secure`

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite